# Solve the initial value problem $x'=h(t)x,x(\tau)=\xi$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the initial value problem $x'=h(t)x,x(\tau)=\xi$.

Do I use separation method?

Does $x=x(t)$? If so, isn't the solution then $x(t)=\frac{1}{h(t)}x'$? I am a little confused what to do...

Comment: What function $x(t)$, when differentiated, is $h(t)x(t)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use separation of variables. Assume first that $\xi\neq 0$. Then, in some interval around $\tau,$ you'll have $x$ different from $0$ (by continuity), and then,

$$h(t)=\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)},
$$
Implying that

$$
\int_{\tau}^t h(s)\textrm{d}s=\int_{\tau}^t \frac{x'(s)}{x(s)}\textrm{d}s
$$
By the change of variables $u=x(s),$ we get

$$
\int_{\tau}^t h(s)\textrm{d}s=\int_{x(\tau)}^{x(t)} \frac{1}{u}\textrm{d}u=\log\left(\frac{x(t)}{x(\tau)}\right)=\log\left(\frac{x(t)}{\xi}\right)
$$ 
and then, we can simply isolate $x(t)$ and get that

$$
x(t)=\xi\exp\left(\int_{\tau}^t h(s)\textrm{d}s\right)
$$
This establishes uniqueness. Checking existence is simply differentiating this formula for $x$ and seeing that it solves the equation under the proper initial conditions.

Comment: Of course, the case $\xi=0$ should be checked separately, but then, the solution must be the $0$ solution by the above argument.